# chi-square goodness of fit from the logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am trying to get the chi-square goodness of fit from my logistic regression where the results are as below.

```
    Call:                   
    glm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 , family = binomial(link = "logit"), data)                 


    Deviance Residuals:                     
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max                     
    -2.0236  -0.7555  -0.5823   0.5303   2.7839                     

    Coefficients:                   
               Estimate    Std. Error   z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept) 3.00E-01    1.51E-01    1.984   0.04725 *
            X1  -5.74E-02   2.35E-03    -24.461 < 2e-16 ***
            X2  1.58E+00    7.84E-02    20.192  < 2e-16 ***
            X3  -9.40E-02   1.64E-02    -5.744  9.27E-09    ***
            X4  -4.63E-05   1.72E-05    -2.693  0.00709 **
            X5  9.67E-02    2.56E-03    37.852  < 2e-16 ***
    ---                 
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1                  

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)                    

        Null deviance: 22942  on 20382  degrees of freedom                  
    Residual deviance: 20495  on 20377  degrees of freedom                  
    AIC: 20507                  

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Then I run the following code to get the goodness of fit and have zero as a result:

```
 > 1-pchisq(regression$null.deviance-regression$deviance, regression$df.null-regression$df.residual)
 [1] 0
```

I think this means my model fits well but I wonder whether I can use the `regression$null.deviance-regression$deviance`as my chi-square value that I report which is quite large as 2446.95.

Is this right?

Comment: It ought to interest you that the sum of the squared "z values" equals $2483,$ which is close to your chi-square value.

Comment: The chi square value is ridiculously large as 2446.95. Do people also report such large number as well?

Comment: In the context of many p-values that are astronomically small, it's hard to understand the sense in which this chi-squared value could be considered "ridiculously large."  Good statistical reporting does state the value of the statistic along with its p-value.

Comment: Ok. So I can report chi square value as such and claim the significance level to be quite small as zero if I am correct.

Comment: Yes.  In fact, there is something a little ludicrous about reporting p-values as small as $\chi^2_5(2446.95) \approx 1.44493\times 10^{-527}$ as if that was any more meaningful than, say, a value of $10^{-16},$ which already is astronomically small.  A standard mechanism is to write something like "$p \lt 10^{-16}$" and leave it at that.